# AWS ECS app fast auto scaling for video encoding. What is the best way?

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, amazon-ecs, jobs, autoscaling

I am currently running a video encoding application on ECS but auto scaling is my biggest problem.

Users start live video encoding jobs from a front end. Once a job is placed, this is added as a redis queue (rq) job that runs on an ECS task placed on a c5d.large instance using ffmpeg.

Autoscaling is currently based on alarms. If cpu is > than a set percentage, a new instance and task is spawned. If cpu is low, instances are checked and if no jobs are running they are destroyed.

This is not a bad solution but it feels clunky and slow. If a user wants to start two jobs one right after the other, it takes a couple of minutes for the instance to spawn + task to be placed (even using warm groups).

Plus cloudwatch alarms take a while to refresh and are not a super reliable way of defining work that is being done (a video encoding at 720p will use less cpu than one at 1080p and thus mess all my alarm settings).

Is there a better solution that someone can guide me to that allows for fast and precise autoscaling other than relying on cloudwatch alarms? I am tempted to try to create my own autoscaling system based on current executing jobs / workers and spawn/destroy instances directly calling the API from my code, but I'm hoping to find a better solution directly from within AWS.

Thanks

Comment: Use aws fargate to run workers and scale your services using your application, not CloudWatch alarms.

Answer (score 0):

I too have this exact problem, AWS already has **mediaconvert/elastictranscoder** but it's just too expensive & I decided to create my own firstly on lambda with [SST.dev](https://sst.dev/) (serverless) where all jobs are a single function invocation but I had issues with **15mins** function timeout mostly because I'm not copying codecs.

scaling at this point I would think is [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/). This is the sort of problem that Kubernetes is intended to handle (dynamic resource scaling on demand). Kubernetes is rather non-trivial. K8s is what the industry has settled on for the most part, so there are probably a lot of reasons to just go that route. You could start with [K3S](https://k3s.io/) (psst! i just knew that today) and move up to K8s when you are ready.

Since you're trying to find a solution directly from within AWS, you can try [EKS](https://aws.amazon.com/eks/) but I'm not completely sure what the best would be.